# Spark-Snwowflake Connection Errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here are the versions I am using:

Spark - 3.0.1

Scala - 2.12.13

Python - 3.7.6

I am having issues running the below code. This is the basic connection to Snowflake via PySpark.

Here is my code:

```
# Spark imports
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# 
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Pyspark-Snowflake") \
    .config('spark.jars','/Users/hana/spark-sf/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.1.jar,/Users/hana/spark-sf/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.1-spark_2.4.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()


# Set options below

sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "XXX",
  "sfUser" : "XXX",
  "sfPassword" : "XXX",
  "sfRole": "XXX",
  "sfDatabase" : "XXX",
  "sfSchema" : "XXX",
  "sfWarehouse" : "XXX"
}

# Set Snowflake source 
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

# Read from Snowflake
#import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  "select * from TABLE limit 100") \
  .load()

df.show()
```

And here is the error I am getting (in Spyder):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:294)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:288)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
20 more
```

What is wrong in my code / versions? I've tried multiple JDC versions and continue to get errors. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error does indicate an incompatible version somewhere as you stated. Are you using the latest Spark connector?  If so, may need to upgrade JDBC version to the latest: https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/releases

Comment: Try this Docker image that has all preinstalled: https://github.com/zoharsan/snowtire

Comment: @SuzyLockwood yes - i am using the latest spark connector. I just tried using the latest JDBC version and now i am getting this error:  Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: The new error sounds like it can't find the Snowflake jars. Have you seen this bit in the docs? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#configuring-the-pyspark-script

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your spark.jars config that you are using the spark snowflake connector for version 2.4. Either re-run with spark version 2.4 installed.

```
pip install pyspark==2.4.4
```

Or use the jar file which is specific to spark snowflake connections for spark 3.0.
The naming convention of which to download can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-install.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using incorrect spark-snowflake jar version.

The naming convention of spark-snowflake jar represents every detail of what is supports.

For eg. `spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.1-spark_2.4.jar`

This jar is supported for spark version `2.4` and Scala and version `2.11`.

Please check the Spark and Scala version present in your system and use/download appropriate spark-snowflake jar version from [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/spark-snowflake)